# Stop remotebuild agent in Mac for secure false

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova

I want to use my Mac to build an app with cordova. So, i used npm to install the remotebuild.

And then now, as you know, i need to set "remotebuild --secure false" for but i got
***remote build server listening on [http] port 3000*** 
return.
So, i knew that i need to stop the remotebuild first but i don't know ***how to stop the remotebuild for set secure false***? 
I checked the remobuildbuild.conf which has been change the secure to false.
But when i cmd the "remotebuild certificates generate" then it show me the ping secure is true. I want to get no pin.

Answer (score 0):

in the terminal window, the agent is running and you cannot type anything hit control + C.
This should delete some builds then exit